# Run PHP code with return value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, return

I want to make code which will run PHP code in background. I made code which will run PHP script, but I don't Know how to get return value from PHP script(does iten exist in MySQL database).

```
            $.post("/* PATH TO THE .PHP FILE */", $("#_hsync_reg_form").serialize(), function(response) {
            if(response)
            {
                // SOME CODE GOES HERE
            }
            else //ERRORS
```

I Know PHP side.

Comment: You need to try [this manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) from jQuery

Comment: `response` should contain the "return value" - if you mean "what PHP outputs" by that...

Comment: Do you mean `run PHP code at server side` ?

Comment: Show us the whole JavaScript code and the code in your PHP file

Comment: @frz3993 Yes, PHP is server-sided

Comment: @CherryDT You mean if is response = 0, there was error and 1 is success? I need load value from MySQL db,  and push it back to user, without refreshing/redicting a page.

Comment: You need to echo something in php to get it to your browser. If your only use 'return $something;' it wont get to your browser

Comment: You can send it as json.

Comment: @Amous If You don't want to help, please leave. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the print,echo statement to return values from php.

example : echo "hello"; print_r($arrays);

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can set the request/response headers as application/json. And then from PHP script send back the response as JSON. Something like following:

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
    ]
}
```

```
<?PHP
$data = /** data to be serialized **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't show any PHP code, this will be a generic answer:

in jQuery style, the ajax request gets back an "output" which can be a single value or an entire json object if you want.

so you could `echo $value;` and it will work because the "response" in your ajax call is the output that any given ajax is listening to (could be any given backend..or even a 3rd party API)

Now if you have an issue and the output is not returning correctly, you will need to post your php code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a non empty response your php script must OUTPUT something...(not just return something).

In your example the callback function is 
`function(response) {...}`

So `response` variable in your example holds the response data.

Whatever the php file located in `"/* PATH TO THE .PHP FILE */"` outputs using php's `echo`,`print`,html outside php tags etc will be returned in `response` variable and you can access it with javascript.